# Listing User.php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

```
$latest_post;

if ( publisher_get_prop( 'show-posts-url' ) ) {

$latest_post = get_posts( array(
        'author'      => $user->ID,
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'numberposts' => 1
));

$latest_post = $latest_post[0];
```

I would like to manipulate this loop to make it load users ordered by who posted lately. How could I do this. I want to sort the authors by latest post order.

Comment: I want to sort the authors by post date. how can i benefit from it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? There is no loop given. And `get_posts` will not list any user, but posts

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the posts? or just a list of users.
if it's just the list of users who recently posted then use [get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

```
$args = array(
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'number'       => '10',
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'orderby'       => 'post',
 ); 
$users = get_users( $args ); //var_dump($dash);
echo '<ul>';
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        echo '<li>'. $user->user_nicename .'</li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

For sorting check this neat function shared by tfrommen at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96292/115240).